# Query about MATLAB interpolant fitting

Tags: matlab, interpolation, curve-fitting

I have a model of a process that is discrete - I also have some experimental data, and I want to work out how well this fits the discrete function; of course, some of these experimental points are 'between' my discrete points, so I need to be able to estimate these to get a goodness of fit: using interpolant fitting in the GUI curve fitting tool yields a perfect fit, whether linear, cubic of shape preserving is used: is there some way I can generate all my interpolant points to compare them with the data points? I've attached an image of 30 of my discrete data points, and the interpolant function that easily joins them.

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9OpA.png - Screencap of discrete function / interp. fit

My second question is can I then find a command line version? I will need to automate this for a few hundred runs to find the best fit, and would be ideal if I could code it into a .m file to basically generate a interpolant fit, and compare this to lab data to get a goodness of fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interpolant "fitting" isn't really fitting... it is just connecting your points with line segments, [or some other shape that improves the smoothness of the curve*].  Regardless of what shape it connects them with, they'll always pass right through your discrete points, meaning a "perfect" fit.

Let me rephrase the question: You have a set of discrete points model_k at time points tm_k generated from a model.  You have another set of discrete points data_k at different time points td_k, and you want to compare them.  Right?

Then all you need to do is resample your model on the same time points as your measured data, then you can compare them.  For each data run:

```
% data is a 1xN column vector of your measured data points
% td is a 1xN column vector of the time points corresponding to d
% model is a 1xM column vector of the model points
% tm is the 1xM time vector for model

model_on_data_time_points = interp1(tm, model, td);

% Here is an example of computing with this resampled vector
difference_vector = data - model_on_data_time_points;
mse = sum(difference_vector.^2) / length(difference_vector);  % mean squared error
```

(*) EDIT: Fixing "line segment" language in response to comment

Comment: NO. Interpolation is NOT just connecting the dots with straight line segments!!!!! Interpolation may be (and often is) connecting the dots with curved pieces.

Comment: That's why I said "regardless of what shape it connects them with".  But you're right, "line segments" is misleading.  I'll edit the answer to correct that.